# Initializing fixed array of strings in C and adding entries to it at run time

Tags: arrays, c, string, char

I am having array of strings in C declared like below

```
    static struct userRolesUpdatePost
{
    char userName[32+1];
    char userGroups[16][32+1];
    unsigned int validtyTime;

}userRolePost;
```

I am initializing above array of strings in structure as below

```
for(int i=0;i<16;i++) { strncpy(userRolePost.userGroups[i], "", 2); } // Initialize string array
```

And I want to add entries at end. while adding entries at end to above array which happens at run time I am doing like below

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    if (strcmp(userRolePost.userGroups[i],  "") == 0)
    {
        printf("Adding new group %s, \n ", name);
        strncpy(userRolePost.userGroups[i], name, 32);
        return OK;
    }
    continue;
}
```

I think we can do better safer and readable than above. Is there better way we can do in C?

Thanks for your time and guidance.

Comment: Keep a count of userGroups you have added so far.  Consider using a data structure that supports the operations you way, say, a queue, and than replace your char userGroups with the struct, that  hold said data instead as an implementation detail.

Comment: userGroups sounds like identities, maybe you have somewhere else and you just need store a handle to each (index, and/or pointer)?

Comment: That `continue` is unnecessary.

Comment: If the code for initialization is executed only once, it can just as well be removed as `static` variables will be default initialized

Comment: @SupportUkraine While that is true, being explicit about initialization and writing self-documented code is good practice - why my answer here recommends `= { 0 };` meaning "yes I definitely want to initialize everything to all-zeroes". Unlike `static userRolesUpdatePost userRolePost;` which could either mean "I forgot to initialize this" or "I don't need to initialize this struct, it will get written to anyway" or "I'm a rockstar programmer who is assuming that everyone knows all the dirty details of C like static storage duration initialization - read my code and tremble in fear".

Comment: @Lundin If you don't know how C works, you'll get into trouble anyway. Writing stuff that indicates you don't know, doesn't make that better.

Comment: @SupportUkraine Yes but one should not write needlessly obscure or ambiguous code just for the heck of it. Same reason as why `if(ptr == NULL)` is preferred over `if(ptr)` and `array[i+1]` is preffered over `(i+1)[array]`.

Comment: @Lundin I'm sure it's just a typo and that you do know that `if(ptr == NULL)` and `if(ptr)` has different meaning. I strongly agree that obscure code constructs shall be avoided but it soon turns into a very opinion based discussion. I'm sure most will agree that `(i+1)[array]` is a "no go". Some would say the same for `*(array + i + 1)` while others find that okay. Re `if(ptr)` I actually think many find that okay. IMO there is no clear line here. It's too opinion based. When it comes to `static` vars, I find it okay to skip an explicit default initialization as it's a well known feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- It's generally good practice to separate type definitions from variable declarations. So I would rewrite the struct as:

  ```c
  typedef struct 
  {
      char userName[32+1];
      char userGroups[16][32+1];
      unsigned int validtyTime;
  } userRolesUpdatePost;

  static userRolesUpdatePost userRolePost;
  ```

  (Or optionally if you are in the Linux fan club, `struct userRolesUpdatePost { ... };` then `struct userRolesUpdatePost userRolePost;`, that's fine as well, just not a style I personally favour.)
- While we are at it, take advantage of C's rules of default initialization:

  ```c
  static userRolesUpdatePost userRolePost = { 0 };
  ```
- `strncpy` is a dangerous function which should almost always be avoided. There's no use for it here since you know the lengths in advance and all parameters passed are sanitized. `strcpy` is then both safer and faster, so use that instead. See [Is strcpy dangerous and what should be used instead?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/281518) to learn about the design problems of `strncpy`.
- `if (strcmp(userRolePost.userGroups[i],  "") == 0)` is acceptable and will likely get optimized well, but it's really just the same thing as `if(userRolePost.userGroups[i][0] == '\0')` so you might as well write that. It won't turn the code slower but it might turn the code faster. Either form is sufficiently readable, so this is just a micro-optimization for speed.
- `continue;` at the end of the loop is just clutter. In general, avoid using `continue`/`goto` "spaghetti programming" keywords. Their presence are pretty much always a sign that a loop should be rewritten in better ways. There are valid uses of them, but they are so few and far in between that it's better to avoid these two keywords entirely.
- Avoid "magic numbers" such as 16 and 32. Replace them with named constants.

---

A cleaned up program that is faster, safer and more readable may look like:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define USER_NAMES_N  32
#define USER_GROUPS_N 16

typedef struct 
{
    char userName [USER_NAMES_N+1];
    char userGroups [USER_GROUPS_N][USER_NAMES_N+1];
    unsigned int validtyTime;
} userRolesUpdatePost;

int main (void)
{
  static userRolesUpdatePost userRolePost = { 0 };

  for (size_t i = 0; i < USER_GROUPS_N; i++)
  {
    // name should be obtained  from somewhere here
    char name[]="something";

    if(userRolePost.userGroups[i][0] == '\0')
    {
      printf("Adding new group %s, \n ", name);
      strcpy(userRolePost.userGroups[i], name);
      return OK;
    }
  }
}
```

---

Note however that storing the strings pointed at by `char*` instead, which you allocate dynamically, might be a much more sensible solution. It gives ever so slightly more execution overhead (and the potential for the usual `malloc` problems) but it saves a lot of space in case you need to allocate long arrays of these structs. Also it removes the 32 character limit if you'd like.

Comment: Obviously it's much better code but not sure it answers op's vague question.  It's refactored not reworked.

Comment: @AllanWind Well it's really just a mini code review. Normally such belongs on the Code Review site but since these are just snippets and fragments, SO is a better place for it and I don't support migration since the question as-is would be off-topic at CR.

Comment: In OPs code the length of `name` isn't know so just replacing `strncpy` with `strcpy` is not a good idea.

Comment: @SupportUkraine I'm assuming that `name` is a sanitized string and not a piece of random unknown data. Sanitizing a piece of random unknown data isn't the job of the `strcpy`/`strncpy` functions, their job is, unsurprisingly, to copy strings. Or in case of `strncpy`, to copy fixed-width, non-nullterminated strings for ancient Unix systems, and then by a lucky accident pad the remaining bytes with zeroes. That's all it ever did, it was never a safe function. Sanitizing a piece of random unknown data is the job of the application programmer, at the point when that data is obtained.

Comment: Just assuming that `name` is already sanitized and not mention it, is IMO not a good idea either. I would guess OP has used `strncpy` because `name` isn't sanitized. That OP seems to have misunderstood what `strncpy` is really doing is another story.

Comment: @SupportUkraine In case it isn't, then `strncpy` won't help you anyway. What makes you think `name` is at least 33 characters long? What if it is a 5 bytes long array and not zero terminated? That bug is not `strncpy`'s job to handle. What if `name` is actually a pointer to `userRolePost.userGroups[i]`? That bug is not `strncpy`'s job to handle. What if it isn't even a string? That bug is not `strncpy`'s job to handle. These are by no means more/less likely scenarios than the one where `name` is a string longer than 32 characters. Which again is not `strncpy`'s job to handle either.

Comment: All you said here is not solved by `strcpy`. It makes no sense

Comment: @SupportUkraine No but `strcpy` is both faster and safer than `strncpy` so it is preferred in some 99% or all use-cases. Unless you are maintaining 1970s Unix source code, then of course carry on using `strncpy` for its intended purpose.

Comment: @Lundin I think you have misunderstood my comment. I'm **not** arguing that `strncpy` is better to use than `strcpy`. My point was only to make clear that OP would need to make sure that `name` will fit inside `userRolePost.userGroups[i]` before calling `strcpy`. I think it's important to mention that clearly as OP seems to have used `strncpy` to ensure exactly that. OP is probably one of the many that have misunderstood what `strncpy` is really doing but things it's a safer version of `strcpy` (which it isn't). The answers proposal re `strcpy` is fine but it should IMO mention length check.